# How do you add a listbox as an input parameter UI element in SSRS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have to add a listbox/dropdownlist to a report in a Visual Studio Business Intelligence project, allowing users to filter a DataSet by the Id of the entity chosen in the listbox. I heard this was possible, but there is no option to add a listbox in the Toolbox in Visual Studio, and looking at the [Report Definition](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd) on microsoft.com, there's nothing there about a listbox.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do what I was tring to do. There is no listbox option, the way I was thinking of it. Instead, if you add a parameter for the report, and use the "available values" section to associate the parameter with, for example, the results of a query, then a listbox/dropdownlist will appear in the header, prompting you to select an item from the list that results from the query.

That's exactly what I wanted to do. I was still thinking in Asp.Net terms though, where a listbox is the same sort of thing as a textbox, for example. I couldn't see why a textbox would be an option in the toolbox, but not somehting like a listbox.

Comment: this thing that you say is not a control, it is a parameter selection control that reporting service add it at the top of report viewer control.
if you want use this report in your application, this controls will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any `listbox` or `dropdownlist` as a built-in control in reporting services.
you must have an application (web/win) for this work and pass your data as a parameter to your report.